# Trigonometric equations with 2 functions

Tags: trigonometry

Given the equation: $\sin^2{x}+\cos{x}=0$

How is it solved?

I think: $\sin^2{x}=1-\cos^2{x}$, but even if I get a quadratic equation with one function (cos), how can I solve it?

Comment: Substitute $u = \cos x$. Solve the resulting quadratic, and then take the inverse cosine of the results. Discard results that don't lie between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: Apply it the same way: $-\cos^2 x + \cos x + 1=0$. $\cos x = {-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4} \over -2}$.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley and find the arccos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. The equation
$$\sin^2 x + \cos x = 0 $$
becomes
$$-\cos^2 x + \cos x + 1 = 0 $$
with the substitution $\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x$. 
At this point, you may solve the quadratic equation in $\cos x$ to find
$$\cos x = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4}}{-2} = \frac{1 \mp\sqrt 5}{2},$$
that is, formally,
$$\cos x  = \begin{cases}
\varphi \\ - \dfrac 1 \varphi
\end{cases} $$
where $\varphi = 1.618033...$ is the *golden ratio*. However, since $\cos x \in [-1,+1]$, the option $\cos x = \varphi$ must be discarded, so that
$$\cos x = - \frac 1 \varphi = \frac{1 - \sqrt 5}{2}. $$
One solution is
$$x = \arccos \frac{1 - \sqrt 5}{2} \approx 2.237$$
in radians (in degrees, about $128.2^\circ$); however, since $\cos$ is an even function, $-x$ must be a solution too. Finally, $\cos$ is $2\pi$-periodic, therefore the other solutions may be found by adding a factor of $2 \pi n$ to $x$ and $-x$, with $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin^2{x}+\cos{x}=0$$

$$1-\cos ^2 x +\cos x =0$$

$$\cos ^2 x -\cos x -1 =0$$

$$ \cos x = \frac {1-\sqrt 5 }{2}$$

$$x= \cos ^{-1} (\frac {1-\sqrt 5 }{2}) \approx 128.17  \text { degrees.}$$